# Plesk API - Disabled Domain returning 0 or 2 status code

Tags: php, xml, api, plesk

So I'm using the Plesk XML api to pull all my webspaces and sites.

I have one webspace and one site set to disabled in my Plesk CP. (Suspending them produces the same result).

The webspace still returns a 0 status code on the XML request, which is meant to meant online.
The site returns a 2 status code, this is completely undocumented.

(https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/12.5/api-rpc/reference/managing-sites-domains/site-settings/general-site-information/node-getgen_info.66550/)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes but you can find status description at https://kb.plesk.com/en/127156

```
status value            value   binary          desсription
STATUS_ACTIVE           0       0000000         active
STATUS_STATUS           1       0000001         suspended
STATUS_WITH_PARENT      2       0000010         suspended because of parent object
STATUS_BACKUP_RESTORE   4       0000100         suspended because of backup/restore
STATUS_ADMIN            16      0001000         suspended by administrator
STATUS_RESELLER         32      0010000         suspended by reseller
STATUS_CLIENT           64      0100000         suspended by client
STATUS_EXPIRED          256     1000000         suspended due to expiration
```

Comment: Yeah, I found that. Contacted Plesk support about it. It's been logged as a bug with the developers that should be fixed in the next update as the web space still returns the wrong code.